# TCL Get The Name Of The Command To Be Deleted

Tags: tcl

I am extending TCL with C++ and my understanding is that when a command is about to be deleted the Tcl_CmdDeleteProc specified at the creation of the command is called. But only the client data is supplied to the Tcl_CmdDeleteProc when it is called. I would like to know the name of the command to be destroyed in the Tcl_CmdDeleteProc, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but you have to be a bit tricky about it.

If you're in the delete callback for a command, that pretty much means that you must have created it in the first place (it's tremendously bad form to insert deletion callbacks for commands created by others) and that means that the `clientData` can really be a pointer to a structure you control. If you put the `Tcl_Command` token (that you got when you created the command) into the structure somewhere, you can fish that out when the command is deleted and use that with `Tcl_GetCommandName` or `Tcl_GetCommandFullName` to get the current name of the command. (The deletion callback comes at a point when the command still has a name, BTW.)

*Be very careful!* The delete callback is called at a time when the command is actually only partially there; it's possible to trigger crashes if you aren't careful. You probably shouldn't call the command from the callback, or rename it, or delete it. It's possibly better to set a trace on the command so that you get notified of name changes. (This is also a mechanism you can use to find out about name changes and deletions of commands that you don't control.) That is because those traces happen slightly earlier, though still when the command is marked for death.